# How can I cleanup least frequently used node packages?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, yarnpkg, systemjs

My system has 1000s of node packages installed mostly via yarn and few via npm. Now I want to cleanup least frequently used node packages, how do I proceed? Is there any package which can track the usage of these over time and help me identify those to be cleaned up?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do two things.

- First you could use the [*npm prune* command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/prune) to unbuild packages that are not listed in the packages.json dependencies. This way you can get rid of those that the package manager cant audit, search for vulnerabilities and fix.
- Second, you could use [webpack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpGLUVbqoYQ) in order to list dependencies and set how they will be loaded, in order to optimize your app.

Hope this help you, or at least give you some ideas to do your research :)